# How can I connect wire to this push button switch

Tags: soldering

[image]

I've tried all the tricks to solder the pin for this push button, to no avail. Though I feel flux may help it stick (not sure), I just feel there has to be a better way. The pins are made of steel like slippery metal, and my solder never sticks.

Is there any jack connector for such pins that I am unable to explore yet?

Thanks for help, and hope this helps some newbie like myself.

Comment: Those are solder tags in the picture, so...

Comment: Are  you able to solder other things? If the parts are very old and corroded you may be able to lightly burnish the pins with a mild abrasive such as a fiberglass or brass brush or Silvo metal polish. The plating is usually thin, and too aggressive sanding will expose the underlying metal, which may or may not be soft-solderable.

Comment: You could try curling the to-be-soldered wire around the connector and use a lot of tin

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'd need some more help. Can you please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @Ananas_hoi I've tried doing that, its not a good solder though, little jerk and it goes off. Not good in real environment.

Comment: Add some photos of you soldering something similar successfully and the results with these items. Include the exact type of solder (preferably a photo of the label on the roll) and any flux you may have used (most electronic grade solder has a mild flux in an internal core or cores).

Comment: @Ouroboros "little jerk and it goes off." if that happens you aren't doing it properly.

Comment: @Ouroboros - "flux may help it stick (not sure)" - electrical solder is not for making things "stick". It is not glue.

Comment: Guys I appreciate your help. I'm a coder trying to do stuff, and never ever soldered things until now. I understand I'm coming out as a noob, but I wish to learn. I'll try flux and let you know my results.

Answer (score 5):

Does nobody know how to solder any more?

Four things I was taught when learning to solder 50 years ago:

1. Clean the soldering iron tip with a copper wire brush and tin it freshly before starting.
2. Scrape the wire end bright with a knife and tin it.
3. Tin the thing it is to be connected to if it isn't pre-tinned. Those tags look pre-tinned. Scrape them lightly to make them bright.
4. Use tools such as pliers to make the mechanical joint. Use the solder to make the electrical joint.

OK five things.

**5. Do not think of solder as being a kind of 'metal glue'.**

You can see in the picture, those tags actually have a little hole for you to poke the tinned wire through, bend into a U shape and squeeze with pliers so it stays there while you bring the solder in one hand and the iron in the other and heat the joint up. Only use extra solder if you need it. You shouldn't. If you have done the preparation properly, the solder will flow quickly and you can whip the iron away after a tiny moment. If you have not prepared, you will cook the whole thing and damage the component and what it is supposed to connect to, and the joint will be bad.

[image]

This shows the bending and squeezing although I would have tinned the wire first:

[image]

I can't imagine soldering without these:

[image]
[image]